# Jquery/JavaScript : Sort a datatable on column that has <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sorting, datatables

This is similar to the problem below but not exactly the same since the post below does not tell about how the user is creating the datatable. I googled a lot but could not find any helpful resource.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476345/jquery-datatables-and-server-side-sorting-in-asp-net-mvc

I also followed below but none works

[Sorting column with anchor tags in jQuery DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899500/sorting-column-with-anchor-tags-in-jquery-datatables)

I have a datatable like below and I am trying to sort on my first column which has an `<a>` element. If I remove `<a>` and use `@Html.Raw(item.ID)` it works fine but sorting does not happen when I use the `<a>` element.
Please let me know how can I sort a datatable on a column that has `<a>` element.

```
<table class="datatable table table-bordered table-hover" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">ID</th>@*this is for sorting purpose*@
            <th class="text-center">ID</th>
            <th class="text-center">Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var item in Model.FieldList)
    {
        <tr>
            @*this is for sorting purpose*@
            <td class="col-md-1">
                @Html.Raw(item.ID)
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1">
                <a href='@Url.Action("StudentDetails", "Admin", new {id=@item.ID})'>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ID)
                </a>
            </td>    
            <td class="col-md-4">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Name)                
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datatable').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "bs_full",
            "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
            "aoColumns": [{ "bVisible": false }, null, null]
        });       
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

**[UPDATE 1]**

As per Damian advice I added the code below. I can notice that for a small fraction of a second I can see the values sorted but datatable is not preserving the order and it is refreshing as if we are reloading the page.

```
"aoColumns": [{ "asSorting": ["asc"], "sType": "html" }, null]
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

Thanks to Damian. I used below. Now my datatable is sorted but getting JavaScript error. Looking into it.

```
"aoColumns": [{ "asSorting": ["asc"], "sType": "html" }, {null}]
```

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Damian for pointing me correct direction. I solved by adding one hidden column and sorted using that column. Please see above for my solution

Comment: I donot know why it is down voted. Can anybody use bootstrap and try to sort the table on a column which as anchor element in that column. You can never sort anchor element. That is what we are trying to address here. Here we are tweaking the solution little bit so that we can show on UI we are sorting as per anchor element column. I guess we need mechanism to let admins know people are just down voting. People when they down vote must tell why they are down voting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1) Update to DataTables above 1.7, because previous versions do not support sorting on HTML elements.

2) Add the sType parameter to that column. This will ignore the HTML in the function sort, in your case, something like:

```
"aoColumns": [
    { "sType": "html" }
   ],
```

Here is [the official documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns) about that.

Comment: Thanks Damian. Since I have 2 columns I gave like this but still it didnot work. I guess I am doing something wrong. Please let me know. "aoColumns": [{ "sType": "html" }, null]

Comment: I tried this also   "aoColumns": [{ "asSorting": ["asc"], "sType": "html" }, null]

Comment: @Ziggler you need to set "aoColumns": [{ "sType": "html" }, {null}]

Comment: Thanks Damian, the above comment nailed the problem. I am accepting this as answer since it works for me. Thank you very much,

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Damian can you please tell how to give null to second column in aoColumns. I am getting syntax error in my javascript. I tried both ways "aoColumns": [{ "asSorting": ["asc"], "sType": "html" }, {null}] -- synaxt error and also "aoColumns": [{ "asSorting": ["asc"], "sType": "html" }, null] - sorting not happening

Comment: Go to the documentation link on my answer and search for sType, then click on 'show details', there is an example.

Comment: Damian.. I saw them and used them to write my code but "aoColumns": [{"sType": "html" }, null] is not sorting and doesnot throws in javascript error in chrome. I am looking into further. Thanks. I appreciate it.