# Add URL to jQuery Datatables data set?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

I have a jquery datatables which is built dynamically, meaning each row is built using a php mysql database call. Creating the table itself is no problem but there are times I want to add hyperlinks to the data displayed in the set.

For example:

```
ID   |    Date       |   Amount
----------------------------
1    | April 1, 2011 |  3.95
2    | April 5, 2011 |  4.55
3    | May 9, 2011   |  19.32
```

the catch is, the dates above would be a hyperlink and the date format in the URL would be in format of YYYY-mm-dd.

When i do this, datatables wants to treat the entire URL as a data element and thus screws up any sorting I can do on the table after the fact.

Anybody had this issue before? I can't seem to find anything online.

Comment: so the Date column looks something like: <td><a href="somepage.html?date=YYYY-mm-dd">May 9, 2011</a></td>??

Comment: so help me understand then because that will sort according the the YYYY-mm-dd date.  Can you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898621/jquery-datatable-plugin-doesnt-seem-to-sort-columns-with-links-properly

Comment: @kasdega - it does not sort by the YYYY-mm-dd

Comment: we have a very similar situation in our code somewhere.  I'll see if I can find it post back if I have something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort non standard columns you can define specific functions: here you can find some of them: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting.

in your case you define your own sorting function like this:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['my-date-asc']  = function(a,b) {
    var x = a.match(/date=(.*?)"/)[1].toLowerCase();
    var y = b.match(/title="(.*?)"/)[1].toLowerCase();
        x = x.replace(/-/g, '');
        y = y.replace(/-/g, '');
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['title-string-desc'] = function(a,b) {
    var x = a.match(/date=(.*?)"/)[1].toLowerCase();
    var y = b.match(/date=(.*?)"/)[1].toLowerCase();
        x = x.replace(/-/g, '');
        y = y.replace(/-/g, '');
    return ((x < y) ?  1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use fnRender() on that column to return any html you want that column to display.

```
bUseRendered: true,
fnRender: function(oObj) {
   var id = oObj.aData[0];
   var normalDate = oObj.aData[1];
   var amount = oObj.aData[2];
   var urlDate = oObj.aData[3];
   var isUrlDate = oObj.aData[4];

   if (isUrlDate) {
      return urlDate;
   }
   else {
      return normalDate;
   }
}
```

Note the

```
bUseRendered: false
```

This tells datatables "for this column when sorting use the data passed back NOT the html rendered"

oObj.aData returns the column data from that row. You could return a couple extra HIDDEN columns which contain the data you need to perform that logic. Then your sorting still works and you also have access to the url you need if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that if there is no link this sorts just fine but because there is a link (html) in the column it doesn't work like you'd expect.  To me it sounds like it has less to do with the date and more to do with the HTML...

I found this:
[jquery datatable plugin doesn't seem to sort columns with links properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898621/jquery-datatable-plugin-doesnt-seem-to-sort-columns-with-links-properly)

Comment: right, I mention that above but surely believe there is a way to ignore the html element. When trying to link above i get the same issue unfortunately. I appreciate the help and will keep looking around.